# Database populated chained drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created this JSP page in which all the drop down menus are populated from database.  This functionality works fine I've tested it.  But now I need to add a function so the third drop down menu (which is Forecast ISC)  only becomes visible when I select a certain field from first menu which is "Type" .So far I haven't created any java script because that's what i need help with! Any suggestions or comment will help!

```
  <form:form action="/analysis/analysisSummary" modelAttribute="shipData"
    method="POST" onChange = 'checkType()'>
    <br>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="20%">Type:<form:select id="type" path="type">
            <form:option value="All">------ All ------   </form:option>
        <form:options items="${analysisEvents}" itemLabel="description"
                        itemValue="code" />
                </form:select>
            </td>


            <td width="20%">Forecast ISC:<form:select id="iscCode"
                    path="iscCode">
                    <form:option value="All">ALL</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${iscCodes}" />
                </form:select>
            </td>

            <td width="30%"><div style="visibility: hidden">
                    Actual ISC: <form:select id="sctry"
                    path="iscCode">
                    <form:option value="All">ALL</form:option>
                    <form:options items="${iscCodes}" />
                </form:select>
                </div>
            </td>
```

HTML:

```
       <form id="shipData" onChange="checkType()" action="/analysis/analysisSummary" method="POST">
    <br>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td width="20%"></td>
            <td width="20%">Type:<select id="type" name="type">
                    <option value="All">------ All ------</option>
                    <option value="U">Unanalyzed</option><option value="H">Pending</option><option value="F">True Hit</option><option value="C">Return Reason</option><option value="S">Parcel Returned</option><option value="T">Long Term Pending</option><option value="Z">Value &gt;2500</option>
                </select>
            </td>


            <td width="20%">Forecast ISC:<select id="iscCode" name="iscCode">
                    <option value="All">ALL</option>
                    <option value="JFK">JFK</option><option value="LAX">LAX</option><option value="MIA">MIA</option><option value="ORD">ORD</option><option value="SFO">SFO</option>
                </select>
            </td>

            <td width="30%"><div style="visibility: hidden">
                    Actual ISC: <select id="sctry" name="iscCode">
                    <option value="All">ALL</option>
                    <option value="JFK">JFK</option><option value="LAX">LAX</option><option value="MIA">MIA</option><option value="ORD">ORD</option><option value="SFO">SFO</option>
                </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="8%"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>

            <td width="20%"></td>
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is simplify the question.  The question doesn't have anything to do with Java or JSP, this is all about jQuery and JavaScript.  Could you post the HTML after the JSP is rendered?

Comment: Sorry about that I did edit my question! So basically when user selects "Long Term Pending" from "type" dropdown that's when the third drop down should appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#shipData').find('#type').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'T') {
                $('#shipData').find('#divIscCode').show();  //To  show only drop down
                //$('#shipData').find('#sctry').val('All'); //To initial value if required.
            } else {
                $('#shipData').find('#divIscCode').hide();
            }
        }).trigger('change');
    });
```

For [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/5fjHc/)

Comment: I've tried this code but for some reason its not working. The Demo you have on the site works but it doesn't work on my end. Remember these drop down are populated from database. This code only works when I Hard code all the fields in the drop downs.

Comment: @Fahad:- for form id="shipData" , for type dropdown id="type" like this three id #shipData, #type, #divIscCode should exist after the JSP is rendered. what version jquery you are using?

Comment: that was the problem its working now!! Again I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I have a personal question for you.. @ThulasiRam Can I have your email address I dont like to post my question here.  You can email me if you like at fshafeeq82@gmail.com  Thanks!